# Select specific parts from a txt file and put in a linked list

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list

I need to make a linked list out of a txt file like this:

```
1 Some 1.5 G
2 Thing 2.3 F
3 Another 6.7 B
```

and the list is:

```
typedef struct list{
 int code;
 char name[255];
 float price;
 char letter;
 struct list *next;
}List1;
```

But how can I select the specific parts in the file and put in the right spot of the list ignoring the space?

Sorry for the stupid question, I'm a newbie in programming.

Comment: read about `fgets` and `sscanf`

Comment: @kbr while your point is valid, it is apparent that diplomacy is not your strong suit. When someone new arrives, it is better to help them learn what is required rather than chastise them. A simple request that they read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is much better than a verbal attack.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin and @ Karthick Thank you for the advices.

Comment: @David point noted. Will do the needful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to open the file with fopen(), assign the return value to a pointer. Then  select your function to read your file(as @Karthick ) mentioned fe. fgets or sscanf. Store the values in temporary variables and assign them to the struct elements.

Like:

```
list.price = tempVar;
strcpy(list.name,tempString);
```